# falla carga de imagen github pages

Tags: imagen, github

[image: No Carga imagen]

No se carga mi imagen en Github Page, la imagen corresponde al fondo del Header? Y el error me dice que el servidor no puede encontrar la imagen, la ubicacion es en la carpeta de img la estructura de es CSS JS img index.html, esta es la direccion del repositorio https://github.com/gumodi35/NetflixClone

Answer (score 0):

Eso es debido a que estás usando rutas absolutas en lugar de relativas.

Cuando pones un `/` al inicio de tu ruta, el navegador intenta buscar la imagen en la dirección raiz, es decir que `/img/header-background.jpg` está apuntando a:

- `https://gumodi35.github.io/img/header-background.jpg` en lugar de
- `https://gumodi35.github.io/NetflixClone/img/header-background.jpg`

Cambia la ruta de la imagen en tu CSS a una relativa:

`../img/header-background.jpg`